# How to use an int and string when adding an image to a JLabel

Tags: java, string, swing, int, jlabel

I am trying to add an int and string when defining a URI like so:

```
Line 38    Icon iconpic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img/CM"+a+".png"));   
Line 39    JLabel pic = new JLabel(iconpic);
```

where "a" is an int.

However I get this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at thebutton.CM.<init>(CM.java:38)
```

I also tried this:

```
    String c = Integer.toString(a);
    String d = "img/CM";
    String e = ".png";
    String g = d+a+e; 
    System.out.println(g);
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource(g));
    Icon iconpic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(g));   
    JLabel pic = new JLabel(iconpic);
```

And got this

```
img/CM0.png
null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The first 2 lines was the output from the .println
This is a picture of the project in NetBeans:

[image]

Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: are you have folder `img` in your project directory?

Comment: Are you getting this exception while running this code from IDE or from JAR?

Comment: Yes, the src package has the code package and the img package

Comment: I get the exception when running it from the IDE.

Comment: Could you try using `new ImageIcon("img/CM"+a+".png");` instead?

Comment: Thats is what I already am using.

Comment: No, your code shows that are using also `getClass().getResource`. I wanted you to try load img without it.

Comment: Sorry, when I don't use getClass().getResource nothing shows

Comment: I use NetBeans. In the OS I made a folder but NetBeans reads it as package.

Comment: I added a picture to show

Comment: I dont see a CM0.png there.

Comment: FFS - try it with hard-coded strings first!

Comment: @atamanroman Thats why there was a problem; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make Java look for non-existent images; CM0.png doesn't exist!

Credits to atamanroman and pshemo

Comment: Actually it was atamanroman who spotted it (that is why +1 on one of his answers from me :D), I just repeated it in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This means `getClass().getResource("img/CM"+a+".png")` returns `null` probably .
Try debugging `getClass().getResource("img/CM"+a+".png")` , such as put a           `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("img/CM"+a+".png"))` and see the value .

Please check if the path is correct .

Here is the link to [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Create an `img` folder under your `source` folder and put the image naming it to whatever `"CM"+a+".png"` evaluates to inside it .

Comment: Ok, but is there a way of making it return "img/CM(The value of a).png?

Comment: When you concatenate that primitive `int` to `String` literal , the resulting expression becomes `String` .

Comment: Hence the error . Check if the path is correct or the mentioned resource exist in that location .

Comment: I make the int into a String and it still returned null

Comment: The problem only happens when I put 2 variables in the URI

Comment: This expression `"img/CM"+a+".png"` cannot be `null` if `a` is a primitive . `getClass().getResource("img/CM"+a+".png")` can be null if the resource `"img/CM"+a+".png"` could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.

Comment: What do you mean by 2+ variables in URI ?

Comment: I added the picture, I couldn't upload the picture directly

Comment: Under the source folder , create a folder named img and put the .png file inside it .

Answer (score 0):

In `Projects` tab right click on your project name, and select `new` -> `Folder`. As folder name use `"images"`

[image]

Now go to `Files` tab and move your images to this folder

[image]

---

Now load your images with

```
new ImageIcon("images/yourImageName.png")
```

Comment: it isn't the problem because what it shows as a package IS a folder as I kept telling you

Comment: @Matthew OK, if you really want to use packages as source folders for images then try it this way `new ImageIcon("src/thebutton/img/CM"+a+".png")` but make sure that `a` is not `0` since I don't see any `CM0.png` in your folder. I will just warn you that this approach can produce many problems in future. Creating separate folder for images outside of packages is better approach.

Comment: The problem was that Java was looking for a non-existent image as you said; thanks!